# Managing python2 and python3 at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scikit-learn, installation

I am taking two courses at uni each requirering you to use two different versions of python, and I am new to both. 
One requires you to use python 3 with jupyter notebook and the other to use python 2 with Spyder. 
I have installed both through anaconda, and python3 is set as my default.

I am trying to import packages from SciKit Learn to use in Spyder with Python 2.7. When i try pip install -U scikit-learn in the command prompt, it says it is allready up to date but refers to the default folder of Anaconda3\lib\sitepackages, which obviously does not help me install it in python 2. 
How do I change this to update the package in Python2 instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you created a new environment for Python 2 through anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

Double check which version of python that the pip you're using refers to:

```
$ pip -V
# pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
$ pip2 -V
# pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip3 -V
# pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

I'm not sure exactly what your setup looks like, but if it's defaulting to  python 3.5 like mine does, then doing a `pip install` will install the package for python3 instead of python2

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I think you are right that i´my default is python3. 
I can't find any pip2 though. I have installed everything with anaconda, shouldn't it be located in the same directory within my anaconda2 folder as it is in my anaconda3 folder?

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use virtualenv to manage different python environments.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 yourenvname
```

For activation use, `source ./yourenvname/bin/activate`

When you activate the virtual environment and use pip command, it will use the pip from the local bin path. (Use `which pip` or `pip -V`to check the location)

Now as I understand you are using Anaconda, you can create a new virtual environment using the `conda` command.

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

For activation use, `source activate yourenvname`

If you do not use these solutions, then you want to find the anaconda's python2.7 bin directory and invoke it. (Try with `pip2`)

Resources - 
https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/